# Why java.lang.IllegalStateException occurs when running Word2VecExample form Scala Spark mllib?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

I am trying to read a text file in *Spark-mllib examples* (Word2VecExample) and create it word vectors. I run it by some text files and it gives no error but when reading one of my files, it gives this error and I am really confuse with that because I tried everything such as file format(*utf-8*) and *ASCII* characters.
this is my source code:

```
package org.apache.spark.examples.mllib

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
// $example on$
import org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.{Word2Vec, Word2VecModel}
// $example off$

object Word2VecExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Word2VecExample")
    conf.setMaster("local[4]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val input = sc.textFile("C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\yelp_labelled.txt").map(line => line.split(" ").toSeq)

    val word2vec = new Word2Vec()

    val model = word2vec.fit(input)

    val synonyms = model.findSynonyms("1", 5)

    for((synonym, cosineSimilarity) <- synonyms) {
      println(s"$synonym $cosineSimilarity")
    }

    model.save(sc, "C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\Edited1Yelp")
    val sameModel = Word2VecModel.load(sc, "C:\\Users\\...\\Edited1Yelp")

    // $example off$

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

And this is the Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" 19/05/29 18:36:29 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_4_piece0 on DESKTOP-T5EN156:64774 in memory (size: 13.0 KB, free: 2.2 GB)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 1 not in vocabulary
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2VecModel.transform(Word2Vec.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2VecModel.findSynonyms(Word2Vec.scala:545)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.mllib.Word2VecExample$.main(Word2VecExample.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.examples.mllib.Word2VecExample.main(Word2VecExample.scala)
```

And line 43 refers to `val synonyms = model.findSynonyms("1", 5)` but I'm sure it's true because I run the program correctly with some other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Spark example and [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/mllib-feature-extraction.html#model), this error raises from `findSynonyms(String, int)` method. There must be a vector for String parameter in this method and if it doesn't exist a vector for this, the error

> Java.lang.IllegalStateException.

appears.
So, in my example there is no vector for the input String parameter "*1*".

Comment: It's clear that you don't know Scala. I don't know Scala too :) So, it was also my problem and tnx for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hello don't know much about Spark. Also can't post comments yet so an answer will have to do. Looking at the documention [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/Word2VecModel.html).

.findSynonyms("string",num) 
"Find "num" number of words closest in similarity to the given word, not including the word itself."

So i can't help wondering is looking for the string "1" not maybe the problem. Off the top of my head i struggle to find 5 synonyms for "1", perhaps "one",maybe "uniary" or potentially "individual". From what I read Spark is a machine learning library so have you tried dumbing down the question? Maybe ask for a single synonym or give a simpler string to search for like "happy". This is just my two cents though, and mostly just curious about what is actually happening.

Comment: I saw the documentation. It was so helpful. I answer my question based on it's content. tnx @Alexande Robinson